# Importing apache logs into piwik

Tags: matomo, log-analysis

I am in the process of switching my site analytics from GA to Piwik and would like to incorporate all the historic data that I can.  I have already concatenated the full trail of apache log files I have in my possession.  However, what I do next is not at all clear to me and the Piwik documentation does not help.  It says something along the lines of

```
python /path/to/piwik/misc/log-analytics/import_logs.py --url=http://analytics.example.com access.log
```

I have my concatenated log file, all.logs, in the log-analytics folder.  I would have thought that I just need to issue

```
python /path/to/piwik/misc/log-analytics/import_logs.py all.logs
```

but that throws up an error message. When I provide the URL to the site in question too I get an error saying that it gets back an HTML document (naturally) which it does not like.

I'd be most grateful to anyone who might be able to put me on the right track here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `--url=http://analytics.example.com` let's you set the URL of Piwik, not your website.

Comment: Thanks Matthieu.  I had figured out the issues in the mean time. 1., as you say, the URL needs to be that for Piwik, not the website.  For example if Piwik has been installed in the piwit subfolder the URL would read http://example.com/piwik.  The second issue, which I had not mentioned in my original question is the idsite parameter which takes numeric values. In my case this was simply --idsite=1 given that I am monitoring just one site with Piwik.